# How to bind to jquery-mobile pagebeforeload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I'm getting desperate trying to get the jQuery mobile *pagebeforeload* event to fire. This just does nothing:

```
 $(document).on("pagebeforeload", function( e, data ) {
        console.log("hello");
    });
```

According to the [JQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html), the syntax is correct. Still, nothing happens. Can anybody tell me why that is?

Comment: You get nothing in your console when switching between external pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're including `preventDefault();` Otherwise, it'll just merrily continue loading.

**Docs:** http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

```
$( document ).bind( "pagebeforeload", function( event, data ){

    // Let the framework know we're going to handle the load.

    event.preventDefault();

    // ... load the document then insert it into the DOM ...
    // at some point, either in this callback, or through
    // some other async means, call resolve, passing in
    // the following args, plus a jQuery collection object
    // containing the DOM element for the page.

    data.deferred.resolve( data.absUrl, data.options, page );

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code worked for me exactly as it is.

[image]

Be sure to note that this will only work if you are loading a separate page. It will not work for internally linked pages because it is not actually loading a page.

Comment: good info. so is there something similar I could call when loading an internal page?

Comment: Well it depends on your situation. What types of things will you be using this for?

Comment: in short: I have a JQM page with 5 panels each containing 2 nested JQM pages. To enable deeplinking, I want to check on pagebeforeload if some.html#page is a nested JQM page and if so, block the original request and fire my own panel-page-loader changepage = I need some way to intercept the first JQM page being loaded to check for panel-deeplinks