# Change page on certain condition (before current page shows up)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to prevent the user to access subpages of my jqm page. To do that I use the `pagebeforecreate` event to check a certain condition and depending on that, change the page displayed (cancel current pageload and redirect or normally load the current starting/main page). The Problem is, that I still see the page flickering up before the `changePage()` is executed even when I call the `preventDefault()` method. I also used a relative URL as the first parameter (`to` = 'page.php') of the `changePage(to, options)` and since my `#subpage1` lies within the `page.php` it should open - which it did - but then the transitions are broken because no real refresh was done.

Note that I have a `page.php` including different `#subpage`'s (such as `#subpage1`, `#subpage2`).

```
jQuery(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#subpage2', function(event, data) {
    if (!isCondition1() && !isCondition2()) {
        // stop loading #subpage2
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery.mobile.changePage(jQuery('#subpage1'), {
            data: 'lang=de&param1=foo&param2=bar',
            reloadPage: true,
            type: 'get'
        });
    }
    // go on loading #subpage2
});

jQuery(document).one('pageinit', '#subpage2', function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Did you try with 'pagebeforehide' event of the first page ?

Comment: Not really because the `#subpage1` is never shown when I go to page.php#subpage2. So that does not make sense.

Comment: Check [the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) at the Page Load events. There is even an example on how to prevent normal navigation. Then you can handle all the page loading yourself.

Comment: Please have a look at the first line of the documentation that states 'Whenever an external page is loaded into the application DOM'. It says `external` and a subpage does not seem to be an external page (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10182406/354436 for that).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the body style to display:none in the html? And then if the page loads correctly you can set it's display property? That should be a 'workaround' to prevent the flicker of the page?